# Differentiate a function by a function

Tags: function, matlab, math, differentiation

I'm just a little bit lost here. I'm using the latest MATLAB release with the symbolic maths toolbox. At the moment I'm working on a system, which has equations like x=theta(t)+2 (of course a lot more complicated and longer). Now I would like to differentiate this equation by theta(t). Hence, I should get x=1. However, if I use the diff(x,theta) command I only get the message Invalid variable.

How do I do it? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just set x=theta+2 (i.e., theta is a symbolic variable, not a function), differentiate that with respect to theta, then substitute in a value or expression for theta later on using `subs`.

Comment: how is theta defined. Is it a fct or an array/matrix?

Comment: @James Yeah that sounds reasonable.

Comment: @Rasman Theta is the changing angle of a robot. Hence it changes over time. Thats why I put it originally as a function of t, time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have the same problem, but using **Maple** or **sympy**. Try substituting theta(t) by theta in the right hand side of the equation and then differentiate wrt. theta.

Comment: I haven't thought about that yet. Yeah I guess that should work. However, it a shame that matlab seems to be unable to do it without this workaround. Thanks!